# Unterschied zwischen «wobei» und «während»

Tags: grammar, preposition

> Er sieht im Wohnzimmer fern, **wobei** sie ihr Schlafzimmer aufräumt.
>
> Er sieht im Wohnzimmer fern, **während** sie ihr Schlafzimmer aufräumt.

Haben sie dieselbe Bedeutung?

Comment: @Stephie I think you should have added a comment to the reason for the edit as it may have offered explanation on the original grammatical issues with the question.

Comment: @Marakai, as the question was focussed on wobei / während, fixing the  main / subordinate clause hiccup was mostly to improve readability and avoid answers focussing on that instead of the core question. OP has been here for over two years and I'm confident that they don't mind. One question at a time here....

Comment: @Stephie :-D I see, no worries then!

Comment: @Marakai no problem, you are very welcome to question the reasons behind an action. Actually, I am glad you did as it shows your interest in the workings of the site. We *love* active new members who are interested in the details and want to learn more.

Comment: @Stephie You are welcome! I guess it's a natural thing: Born in Germany but emigrated to the Anglo-Saxon world a long time ago, I straddle both worlds. ;) Well, according to friends & family back in German I need to practise my German nowadays. :D

Answer (score 3):

Beide genannten Konjunktionen, *während* und *wobei*, können sowohl Gleichzeitigkeit als auch Gegensätzlichlichkeit ausdrücken, allerdings bezieht sich *wobei* stärker auf die Handlung des Subjekts und *während* stärker auf den Zeitraum des Hauptsatzes. Im Beispiel wäre daher *während* eindeutig idiomatischer. Würde das Subjekt nicht von *er* auf *sie* wechseln, wäre auch *wobei* oder – bevorzugt – eine Umstellung mit *dabei* möglich:

> - Er sieht im Wohnzimmer fern, **wobei** er aufräumt.
> - Er sieht im Wohnzimmer fern und räumt **dabei** auf.

Normalerweise steht die Haupthandlung, also hier wahrscheinlich das Aufräumen, im (ersten) Hauptsatz, daher klingt das Beispiel immer noch etwas seltsam, also besser:

> - Er räumt das Wohnzimmer auf, **wobei** er fernsieht.
> - Er räumt das Wohnzimmer auf und sieht **dabei** fern.

Im Zweifel ist *während* meistens angebrachter. In einem Hauptsatz würde es bei vorwiegend zeitlicher Bedeutung durch *währenddessen* oder *gleichzeitig* ersetzt werden. Für vorwiegend vergleichende Bedeutung gibt es verschiedene Möglichkeiten, z.B. *(wo)hingegen* und *aber* oder *(je)doch*, die nicht so gut mit dem beiordnenden *und* funktionieren:

> - Er sieht im Wohnzimmer fern und sie räumt **gleichzeitig** ihr Schlafzimmer auf.
> - Er sieht im Wohnzimmer fern und sie räumt **währenddessen** ihr Schlafzimmer auf.
> - Er sieht im Wohnzimmer fern. Sie räumt **währenddessen** ihr Schlafzimmer auf.
> - Er sieht im Wohnzimmer fern. Sie räumt **hingegen** ihr Schlafzimmer auf.
> - Er sieht im Wohnzimmer fern. Sie räumt **jedoch** ihr Schlafzimmer auf.
> - Er sieht im Wohnzimmer fern, **wohingegen** sie ihr Schlafzimmer aufräumt.
> - Er sieht im Wohnzimmer fern, **doch** sie räumt ihr Schlafzimmer auf.
> - Er sieht im Wohnzimmer fern, **aber** sie räumt ihr Schlafzimmer auf.

Prinzipiell ließe sich auch *zeitgleich* statt *gleichzeitig* verwenden, aber zumindest auf mich würde ersteres auf gleiche Start- und Endzeit, mithin Dauer, hindeuten, während letzteres nur eine zeitliche Überlappung erfordert.